# How to reshape a pandas series after converting to numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testpd = pd.Series([[[32, 43], [453, 565]], [[32, 43], [453, 565]]])
```

the shape of it is `(2,)`

I convert this into `numpy` array like the following

```
testnp = testpd.to_numpy()
```

the shape of the numpy array is `(2,)`

but ideally, it should be `(2, 2, 2)` or whatever the actual dimensions are, like the shape of `testnps`  here is `(2,2,2)`

```
testnps = np.array([[[32, 43], [453, 565]], [[32, 43], [453, 565]]])
```

I tried to do `testnp.reshape(2,2)` but it gave an error "`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (2,2)`".

How can I reshape the array to get the ideal `(2,2,2)` shape?

Comment: `testnp = np.array(testpd.to_list())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can convert the pandas series into a list then cover that into numpy array. You can do

```
testnp = np.array(testpd.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
testpd = pd.Series([[[32, 43], [453, 565]], [[32, 43], [453, 565]]])
testnp = testpd.to_numpy()
testnp = testnp.tolist()
testnp = np.asarray(testnp)
testnp.shape
```

Output : (2,2,2)

Answer (score 0):

This works to:

```
out = np.stack(testpd)
print(out.shape)
```